# Reverse engineering MQL files

Tags: reverse-engineering, mql4, mql5, mql

Is there any body know how to reverse engineering MQL expert adviser files?
mq4 or mq5 is file format that used for Meta Trader platform.

I tried using cutter to disassemble  the codes but it doesn't work.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are trying to ask is decompiling an ex4 file to mq4 file. I have done research on it and what I can tell you is it is no longer possible. MQL4 have upgraded. Feel free to do more research. I am just telling you what i found out then.